# How to start building a statistical regression analysis model with multiple categorical/discrete input variables of high dimension in Python

Tags: machine-learning, regression, statistics, logistic-regression

I'm fairly new to data science and ML. I have data of an item going through a release process. I have collected data on various variables such as "product category", "product line", "design country", "hour of day started" and I also have data on "total time" which is the time it took the item going through the entire process. In total I have 18 different input variables where each variable is either a categorical or a discrete number such as "hour of day started".

```
Design_cntry      Prod_category    prod_line   ...   time_minutes
   A                  A1             A11       ...     43.2
   B                  B1             A11       ...     20.1    
   C                  E1             B11       ...     15.0
  ...                ...             ...       ...     ....
```

I want to build a statistical regression analysis model in python which outputs the probability of a statement. Say for instance P(time > 1000 min | product category = A, product line = B, ... ) and am wondering how to tackle this problem? Are there any general ways of doing this? Or good articles/literature on this topic anyone could recommend?

I only have non negative data, so maybe there are any good regression forms based on exponential distributions?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to pre-process your data. it includes encoding your categorical variables. You can either do it using `pandas.get_dummies`, or `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` in your pipeline. Based on the algorithm you want to use, you usually have to standardize your numerical variables. this can be done using any of `sklearn.preprocessing` methods such as `StandardScaler`.

If you want to do logistic regression, you have to categorize your output variable - time - to classes like ['less than 1000 min', 'more than 1000 min']. Otherwise, if you want to keep time as it is, you are doing a multiple regression.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I believe that as of the time being I will look into the multiple regression. Do you have any litterature, articles or examples you would recommend for this task?